# after site update page shows old content

Tags: html, flash

Is there a way to make, that after any swf changes, site would open newly. The problem is that, if i uploud new swf, and enter to site for example with Chrome browser it shows me old content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where you load your swf, include an everychanging parameter such as: (in asp.net c#)

```
<object data="shockwave.swf?<%= DateTime.Now.Ticks %>"></object>
```

this should always ensure that your swf is loaded new every time, and not cached.

Comment: But a problem with using an evercharging value is that the swf is never cached, so it is not cached when it should be either. If a user revisits your page and the swf has not changed, it will still be downloaded from the server again, since the URL has changed (new value for DateTime.Now.Ticks). A better solution, in my opinion, is to instead use a version number in the URL. Each time you upload a new swf, you also change the version number, so the URL will for example be mySwf.swf?v=1 and the next time mySwf.swf?v=2 and so on. That way it can be cached when it is not changed.

Comment: indeed Lars, I'd use my method 99% of the time in a purely development manner, until I was happy with the SWF, and then after that I'd use a versioning system as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clearing your whole browser history each time try <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh the page.

This should reload all the cached content (your swf).